# Multiselect rows in listbox based on string

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a multiselect listbox that has around 60 values, the user can go through and select anything they want I can successfully read everything selected and output it as one line like this "1,2,3,4,5" and store that value.  The problem I currently have is when the user needs to edit what was selected.  How can I reselect the listbox items based on the string "1,2,3,4,5" that was stored earlier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after a lot of searching, here is the code

```
Dim strValue As String
Dim strArray() As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim startRow As Integer

strValue = rsPrints("ctype")'Get string of row values
strArray = Split(strValue, ",", -1, vbTextCompare)'My string required splitting to remove commas and moving to an array

x = 0 'Set array start point to 0

For Q = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray) 'Run through array
    startRow = strArray(x)
    Me.formctype.Selected(startRow) = True
    x = x + 1
Next
```